# Laravel Livewire component not re-rendering

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I have a notifications component that I'm trying to emit an event to and get it to refresh and show new notifications to the user. I've verified that I'm receiving the event, and the `refreshNotifications` method is being called, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get the actual component to update. It's getting super frustrating at this point.

Here's my component:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Components;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Notifications extends Component
{
    public $notifications;
    public $notificationCount = 0;

    protected $listeners = ['refreshNotifications'];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->notifications = $this->user->fresh()->unreadNotifications;
        $this->notificationCount = $this->user->fresh()->unreadNotifications->count();
        return view('livewire.components.notifications');
    }

    public function clearNotifications()
    {
        $this->user->unreadNotifications()->update(['read_at' => now()]);
    }

    public function refreshNotifications()
    {
        //can verify here that the event successfully emitted to this component. No refresh happens though.
        $this->render();
    }
}
```

And here's my blade view:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" x-data="{ open: false }">

    <a @click="open = !open" @click.outside="open = false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle show" id="notificationDropdown" role="button">
        <i class="mdi mdi-bell-outline h3"></i>
        @if ($notificationCount)
            <div class="indicator">
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
        @endif
    </a>

    <div x-show="open" class="dropdown-menu p-0 show" data-bs-popper="none">
        <div class="px-3 py-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between border-bottom">
            <p>{{ $notificationCount }} New Notifications</p>
            @if ($notificationCount)
                <a role="button" wire:click="clearNotifications" class="text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-notification-clear-all"></i>Clear all</a>
            @endif
        </div>
        @foreach ($notifications as $notification)
            <div class="px-3 py-2" wire:key="notification-{{ $notification->id }}">
                <a role="button" class="d-flex align-items-center py-2">
                    <div class="flex-grow-1 me-2">
                        <h5>{{ $notification->data['title'] ?? 'Test Title' }}</h5>
                        <p class="tx-14 text-muted"><em>{{ $notification->data['body'] ?? 'Test body' }}</em></p>

                        <p class="tx-12 text-muted">{{ Helper::timeElapsedForHumans($notification->created_at) }}</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</li>
```

Not sure if it's helpful, but the xhr response is this:  `{"effects":{"html":null,"dirty":[]},"serverMemo":{"checksum":"c980388fe95899e9055bfc363bd57c5d80916fe581b5b7983109cdba20db2f33"}}`

Other questions on SO are related to not being in a single root element. That's not my issue. I have no idea why this isn't working. I feel like I've tried everything.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define what event is called in the listener, for example:

```php
protected $listeners = ['refreshNotifications' => '$refresh'];
```

See here:
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#magic-actions

Comment: Actually you don't. If the method name is the same as the event name, Livewire will do the rest. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#event-listeners

Comment: Yeah, but this way at the moment you just rerun the ``render()`` method, what means that no new data is loaded, because you do not run ``mount`` for example.

Comment: No, the mount method is only called once, when the component is first loaded (https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks#class-hooks). "Runs once, immediately after the component is instantiated, but before render() is called. This is only called once on initial page load and never called again, even on component refreshes". I've already tried using `$refresh` magic action and it doesn't produce anything different than what I'm currently doing.